# Java while not working and robot not sending enter

Tags: java

Hey guys so am making this robot to send message number of times via jtextfield3

Also the enter is not working any help thanks!
Error when ran:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
    at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Robot.java:358)
    at Roblox.Main.sendkeys(Main.java:12)
    at Roblox.GUI$1.actionPerformed(GUI.java:33)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

the line

```
public static void sendkeys(String text) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        String lol = text.toUpperCase();
        for(int i=0;i<lol.length();i++) {
            robot.keyPress(lol.charAt(i));
        }
    } catch(java.awt.AWTException exc) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText())) {

                    Robot r = new Robot();
                    r.delay(Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText()));
                    Main.sendkeys(textField1.getText());

                    Robot okRobot = new Robot();
                    okRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    okRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    i++;
                }

            } catch(java.awt.AWTException exc) {
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        }
    });
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, not just the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void sendkeys(String text) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        String lol = text.toUpperCase();
        for(int i=0;i<lol.length();i++) {
            robot.keyPress(Character.getNumericValue(lol.charAt(i)));
        }
    } catch(java.awt.AWTException exc) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }

}
```

Notice `robot.keyPress(Character.getNumericValue(lol.charAt(i)))` converts your character to an int before passing to  `Robot.keyPress(int c)`

When you pass a `char` in a method, it is automatically converted to type `Character`, not type `int`

Comment: Upvoted this answer since it's simpler and likely works in all cases like this.

Comment: Interesting. I'm curious why now. I'll run some tests myself when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: NonSecwitter's answer is simpler and probably works in all situations, so this answer is probably redundant.**

The problem is with this line:

```
robot.keyPress(lol.charAt(i));
```

You need to pass `int`s to `Robot.keyPress(int)`, not `char`s.

The best thing to do would probably be to get the `char`'s `int` value:

```
int c = Character.getNumericValue(lol.charAt(i));
```

And then convert it to a `KeyEvent` constant:

```
int k = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
```

That will translate the character to the corresponding key code, which I think is what you want. To be honest, I'm not sure if the second step is needed though.

Comment: This won't work, the proper signature for that method is `public static int getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(int c)`

Comment: Will getting the numeric value like in your answer always work? Somehow I feel like it's not an exact mapping of numeric value to key code.

Comment: Hmmm, well, `Robot.keyPress()` is looking for an int, not a keycode. I 'm not sure what the caveat about Unicode in the method documentation implies for this, but it seems like you should get a standard mapping for the characters. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)

Comment: Well, `Robot.keyPress()` is meant to be used with the int constants defined in `KeyEvent`, judging by the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress(int). Yours will probably work most of the time but I feel like it would be safer to convert the numeric value to a `KeyEvent` constant.

Comment: I think you're right, because `keyPress()` is first calling `checkKeyCodeArgument()` which evaluates the following expression `if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED)`... I suppose either method would work if `Character.getNumericValue()` returned the same integer as each corresponding KeyCode constant.

Comment: Comparing these two documents, it looks like they should have the same integer value.   

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_0

    http://www.asciitable.com/
  Although KeyCodes handles a lot of special keys on the keyboard like F1 - F12 etc.

Comment: Looks like you're probably right. I might do some testing tonight to see if I can come up with a definitely answer.